# How to fix compilation errors that mention "stray ‘\342’" and "stray ‘\200’"?

Tags: compiling, c

I wrote this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf(“Hello World\n”);
return 0;
}
```

I saved it as `first.c` and tried to compile but receiving this problem I have installed even gcc compiler too.

```
$ gcc first.c -o first1
first.c: In function ‘main’:
first.c:4:1: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
first.c:4:1: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
first.c:4:1: error: stray ‘\234’ in program
first.c:4:11: error: ‘Hello’ undeclared (first use in this function)
first.c:4:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function 
it appears in
first.c:4:17: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘World’
first.c:4:17: error: stray ‘\’ in program
first.c:4:17: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
first.c:4:17: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
first.c:4:17: error: stray ‘\235’ in program
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you copy this program from some other word processor or document like Libre office or Microsoft Word?

Comment: if you have copied the code from somewhere then rewrite the code on your own as the code that you have copied may have some unwanted codes embedded in it.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that you have Unicode quotation marks instead of ASCII quotation marks; probably your editor automatically changed them, or you copied the text from a site that does this automatically in its authoring software. Replace the quotes with normal ASCII quote (0x22, ") and it should work.

Fixed source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 I was wondering how he got those back/forward quotes in there.

Comment: Unicode vs. ASCII quotation marks might not be the best way to state the distinction, since the correct quotation marks for strings in C (`"`) are Unicode characters, too. (They *also* happen to be ASCII characters but anytime someone is choosing between the two, their file is probably saved in some Unicode format. On a Unix-like system, usually UTF-8.)

Comment: other sneaky characters are the `–` instead of the `-`.

Answer (score 2):

You're enclosing your string in the wrong kind of quotes.

You have:

```
“Hello World\n”
```

You should instead have:

```
"Hello World\n"
```

While the quotes you've used look similar, they are not recognized by a C compiler as enclosing a string. Thus, you get error messages about unrecognized Unicode characters, and you get error messages showing that the contents of the string are being interpreted as unquoted program code.

You will note that the quotes you've used have separate characters for beginning and ending a quotation (they are curved the way quotes are often typeset). Many word processors--as [Jobin suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272741/problem-in-compiling#comment342351_272741)--will automatically turn simple `"` quotes into such fancy quotation marks. If you're using a word processor to compose C programs, you should use a text editor instead.

Ubuntu comes with `gedit` installed by default (though there are many other text editors to choose from, too). Like many text editors, `gedit` provides syntax highlighting for many programming languages including C (so different text in your program will shown in different colors to signify its meaning), which is a handy feature and makes a text editor *much more convenient and user-friendly* for programming than a word processor.

*This might be Ubuntu-specific, if you're used to a text editor on another platform that automatically reduces pasted quotations marks to the non-fancy version. But this question might end up getting closed and migrated to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).*

Comment: problem solved.my program is compiled.tanx alot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sed` command to fix these issues.

This will give you a quick preview of what will be replaced.

```sh
sed -re 's/”|“/"/g' File.txt
```

This will do the replacements and put the replacement in a new file called `WithoutSmartQuotes.txt`:

```sh
sed -re 's/”|“/"/g' File.txt > WithoutSmartQuotes.txt
```

This will overwrite the original file:

```sh
sed -i .bk -re 's/”|“/"/g' File.txt
```