# Fix Compilation Error: stray \200 , stray \213 and stray \342?

Tags: gcc, c

Here is a simple code that adds two numbers in each thread and then gives total balance in the end:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int currentBalance=100,newBalance=0,oldBalance=0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void* thread1(){
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
oldBalance = currentBalance;
newBalance = oldBalance + 10000;
currentBalance = newBalance;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void* thread2(){
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
oldBalance = currentBalance;
newBalance = oldBalance + 5000;
currentBalance = newBalance;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void* thread3(){
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
currentBalance = currentBalance;
newBalance = oldBalance + 5500;
currentBalance = currentBalance;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main()
{
pthread_t trd1,trd2,trd3;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_create(&trd1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
pthread_join(trd1,NULL);
pthread_create(&trd2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
pthread_join(trd2,NULL);
pthread_create(&trd3,NULL,thread3,NULL);
pthread_join(trd3,NULL);
printf("Current Balance: %d\n",currentBalance);
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile it using command

```
gcc -pthread task6.c
```

And here is the error:
[image]

I don't know what's wrong, the code is just fine. Please guide me a bit. 
Thank You!

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code from somewhere (possibly a web page)? most likely, some non-ascii characters crept in - see [How to fix compilation errors that mention “stray ‘\342’” and “stray ‘\200’”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272741/how-to-fix-compilation-errors-that-mention-stray-342-and-stray-200)

Comment: @steeldriver Yes I did, then I pasted it here, and again copied it. Now it's working fine :)